# Reparametrization of rational Bézier curve

Tags: geometry, curves, mathematical-modeling, bezier-curve, spline

I am trying to solve the following task

Using rational Bézier curve find the control points and weights of one sixth of a circle $c_1$, such that $$c_1(0)=\{3,0\},c_1(1)=\{\frac{3}{2},\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\},c_1(\pi/4)=\{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{3}{\sqrt2}\}.$$

I have calculated the control points $\{3,0\},\{3,\sqrt{3}\},\{\frac{3}{\sqrt2},\frac{3}{\sqrt2}\}$,their respective weights $\{1,\frac{\sqrt3}{2},1\}$ and their knots $\{0,0,0,\pi/4,\pi/4,\pi/4\}.$

I don't know how to proceed from here with reparametrizing the curve so that the wanted equalities hold.

Comment: This is a good question. I assume it’s from a course homework assignment. Are the other questions available somewhere? I’d like to see them. How about lecture notes? Thanks.

Comment: The lecture notes are not in English but the Mathematica assignments are. I can share those with you if you tell me how you would like to do that.

Comment: French or German or Japanese are fine. Thanks.

Comment: Dropbox folder here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/irbo9u9ixf2y9b0vrd6p9/h?rlkey=gw2whv4zy5k5qayfsp9rrnhx7&dl=0

Comment: It's in Czech. However as I said in another comment, the material in https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/ covers alot of the course. I dropboxed you the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different hint …

You have constructed a curve that has the correct shape (it’s the desired circular arc), but its parameterization is not what you want.

You can change the parameterization by changing the weights. But you need the shape of the curve to remain unchanged. The key point is this: the shape of the curve will not change long as you don’t change the quantity
$$
\sigma = \frac{w_0w_2}{w_1^2}
$$
You can arbitrarily set $w_0 = 1$, and then adjust $w_1$ and $w_2$ to get the parameterization you need. Specifically, you just have to find $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $\sigma = \tfrac43$, as before, and such that $c(\pi/4)$ has the desired value.

Comment: I think this is the intended solution, I have solved the problem by using the following theorem: If $c(t)$ is a rational Bézier curve with the control points $P_0,...,P_n$ and weights $w_0,...,w_n$ and $\lambda>0$, let $t(s)=\frac{\lambda s}{((\lambda-1)s+1}.$ Then $c(t(s))$ has the same control points as $c(t)$, its weights are $w_0,w_1\lambda^1,...,w_n\lambda^n$ and $c(t(s))=c(t)$.

Comment: The $t(s)$ transformation you mentioned is the linear fractional transformation that I was talking about. It’s not true that $c(t(s)) = c(t)$, but the original and reparameterised curves do have the same shape.

Comment: @Bubba 1) Following your remark, I have modified my answer 2) Do you have a reference document to advise about waighted rational Bezier curves ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I used the following page for information, I hope it helps you aswell https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/

Answer (score 1):

I will proceed by successive logical steps.

1. As you are given 3 points connected by an arc of circle : this (unique!) circle $(C)$ is easily found to have its center in $(0,0)$ and its radius $3$.
2. Now remember that the classical parametrization of the *unit* circle is (so called "half-angle formulas" with $t=\tan(\alpha/2)$ ) is given by

$$x=cos(\alpha)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \ \ y=\sin(\alpha)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

(with uniform speed). **These formulas are naturaly rational Bezier formulas**

Therefore we can take as initial rational Bezier formulas for (C) are :

$$x=3 \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \ \ y=3\frac{2t}{1+t^2}  \ \text{for} \ 0 \le t \le 1/\sqrt{3}$$

3. Why these values of $t$ ?

No problem for value $t=0$ for which $x=3,y=0$ as awaited.

For value $t=1/\sqrt{3}$, it is obtained by solving :

$$\frac32=3 \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \ \text{or the equivalent eq.} \  \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}=3\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

The same operation for the intermediate point gives $t=\sqrt{2}-1$.

4. Therefore the re-parametrization issue boils down to find an homographic transform (linear fractional transformation) :
   $$y=\frac{ax}{x-b}$$

passing through points $$(0,0), (\sqrt{2}-1,\pi/4),(1/\sqrt{3},1)$$

[image]

with :
$$a = (\pi/4)\frac{(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{3} - 1)}{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3} - \pi/4)}\approx 3.2655$$

$$ b =-\frac{(\pi/4)(\sqrt{2} - 1) - \sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{3} -\pi/4}\approx-1.3080$$

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply. From what I've understood from your comment, I have calculated the linear functions $s_1,s_2$ so that $s_1(0)=0,s_1(\pi /4)=\sqrt{2}-1$ and $s_2(\pi/4)=\sqrt2-1,s_2(1)=1/\sqrt{3},$ which yields $s_1(z)=\frac{\sqrt2 -1}{\pi}4z$ and $s_2(z)=z\frac{4(-3+3\sqrt2-\sqrt3)}{3(-4+\pi)}-(\frac{-12+12\sqrt2-\sqrt3 \pi)}{3(-4+\pi)}).$ I'm not sure if this is correct and if so, then does this reparametrization change the control points and their weights I have chosen in the original post?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't taken the time to see what was your solution looking like ; besides, I am not that familiar with the conventions used for weights and control points in this context. My answer was just there to show your issue from another perspective.

Comment: If you use a piecewise linear function to do the reparameterization, you will end up with two Bézier curves, instead of one. The right reparam function is a linear fractional transformation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation

Comment: @bubba You are perfectly right. I hadn't paid attention. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have seen the answer by @Bubba addressing directly the issue. Wixhing that my answer, now correct (thanks to Bubba) brings some little supplementary light).

Comment: @JeanMarie. Good answer. I like it because it’s elementary, so doesn’t use any obscure theorems about weight adjustments. If you want to know more about rational Bézier curves, then the book by Gerald Farin is a good place to start.